# How to Answer Question about Type 1 Error in Probability Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

[image]

a) You minimise the probability of a Type 1 error with a lower significance level, i.e. 1% instead of 5%. So, to answer this, would I pick out the degrees of freedom (3 - 1?) and the critical value under the 1% column on the t-table?

b) P(Type 1 error) = the significance level. How do I use the information in the table to calculate this?

c) Would it be $$0.9^3 = 0.729?$$

I haven't seen a question like this before, so I'm trying to build some intuition with this kind of problem. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle 1^{st} \text{ thing you need to know is that } P\left( T(X) \in \text{Rejection Region}\right)_{H_0} = P(\text{ TYPE 1 ERROR})$

$\text{where T(X) is the test statistic with which you conduct the testing}$

In your case T(X) is $\bar{X}$

And since $H_0:p=1 \text{ against } H_1:p\le 1$ your critical region will look like $T(X)\le C \Rightarrow \bar{X}\le C$

So if you want to minimize $P(\bar{X}\le C),\text{ you  will have to reduce C}$

If previously C was set to be $\frac{2}{3}$ changing C to $\frac{1}{3}$ will reduce your type 1 error.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! So, does that mean that P(Type 1 Error) is lowest if T(X) = 0 in this case?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Thanks. For (b), since the decision rule involves the sample mean = 1, and the P(Type 1 Error) = significance level, would the answer be $$1^3?$$